# animate.css не работает

Tags: animate

```
<div class="header__arrows">
            <a href="#" class="animated fadeInDown infinite">
                <img src="img/arrows-down.svg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
```

css код элемента

```
.header__arrows{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left:210px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

подключил в head эту ссылку

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://animate.style/),названия классов несколько отличаются.

```css
:root{
  --animate-duration:1s;
  --animate-delay:1s;
  --animate-repeat:1;
}
.header__arrows{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left:210px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
<div class="header__arrows">
  <a href="#" class="animate__animated animate__fadeInDown animate__infinite">test</a>
</div>
```